# Error when connecting to a SAML 2.0 IdP that uses shibboleth

Tags: .net-6.0, saml-2.0, shibboleth, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using the `ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0` library with .Net 7 project to connect to a SAML 2.0 IdP.

I tested it first using Okta SAML and it worked great!

However, when I try another SAML 2.0 IdP that uses SAML 2.0 and shibboleth, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: UnableToDecode


400 Bad Request
https://physics.lab.xxx.edu/idp/profile/Shibboleth/SSO?SAMLRequest=
kjrtgtboMwDIZfBeUOCSmDNgKkar1U2rRpTDvsMgUwIhIkWWykPf7Sbof1sqNtff79uUa9
LtKr40azfYHPDZCSr3WxqH4mDduCVU6jQWX1Cqhoo96nrg16TCgfHLnBLewv8z%2BiES
GQcZYl51PDPnKYoNqLPp32UqSFFHnaT9UuHcShlGN5EJwhtrIGASPTsLgigogbnC2Sth
RbQso0l6koX%2bhuyt3dlZncHd5Zcoo2xupLWsNmIo%2BKcx8v8C5Q5g1RBuPGzeh5NJ
nMArybTd%2B7BWjmXffE2vqqpK6JoX2OyMXk3lkLA7lQ85v5b3n7z%2FYbAAD%2F%2Fw
MA&RelayState=ReturnUrl%3D%252F
```

When I step through my app in Visual Studio, it errors out at the end of this controller login method:

```
[Route("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
    var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
    binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> { { relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/") } });

    return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)).ToActionResult();
}
```

This is the metadata used by my app:

appsettings.json:

```
"Saml2": {
"IdPMetadata": "https://physics.lab.xxx.edu/idp/shibboleth",
"Issuer": "SSOLoginApp",
"SignatureAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256",
"CertificateValidationMode": "None",
"RevocationMode": "NoCheck"
}
```

The only thing I can think of is it maybe because this IdP uses `shibboleth`?

**Decoded SAML 2.0:**

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
ID="_2efe780b-f120-4201-bf73-c0962d690701" Version="2.0" 
IssueInstant="2022-12-06T16:42:56.239Z" 
Destination="https://physics.lab.xxx.edu/idp/profile/Shibboleth/SSO">
  <saml2:Issuer>LabLoginApp</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the IdP expect you to use a PostBinding?

I can't decode the SAMLRequest you are sending either

Try to decode on https://www.foxids.com/tools/Saml
[image]

Comment: Thanks Anders!  I was able to decode it and I put the results up above in my original question.  But it doesn't show any errors so I'm not sure what it means?

Comment: The AuthnRequest looks valid but is for some reason not accepted by the IdP. You need to ask the IdP to look in there log and tell you what they think is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I did reach out to the IdP. They said they sign assertions for SAML.  Is this something itfoxtec handles or would I need to research another library?  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, could it be that the IP using SAML 2 and shibboleth is causing this issue? Or is itfoxtec able to handle shibboleth?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes the library support signed assertions by default. Maybe you need to sign the AuthnRequest, it is done by setting the Saml2Configuration.SignAuthnRequest = true  https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Configuration/Saml2Configuration.cs#L67